# Javascript: how do I get the <option> string?

Tags: javascript

I need to get the name of an option item select using javascript but don know how:

```
<select id="filtro_1" class="form-control" onchange="javascript:atualizaCombos(this);" style="box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);">
    <option value="">Todos</option>
    <option value="4">Carros</option>
</select>
```

I need to get the word "Carros" and not the value=4

Anyone?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This answers it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript

Comment: *I need to get the name of an option item select using javascript* **When?**

Answer (score 0):

```
let text = document.querySelector('#filtro_1 option:checked').textContent;
```